# SelectedIndexChanged for multiple RadionButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindexchanged

I have 3 RadionButtonList that are wired to same SelectedIndexChanged event, intentionally. Is there a way to ascertain in the event which RadioButtonList just had one of its items clicked programmatically?

Comment: look in Properties -> Events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ID` attribute of your RadioButtonList objects to do this, and just get the ID of the `sender` object whenever the event is fired.

```
protected void RadioButtonList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string listName = ((RadioButtonList)sender).ID
    // listName = RadioButtonList1 or RadioButtonList2 or whatever the ID is set to.

    if (listName == "RadioButtonList1")
    {
        // Rest of your code goes here, now that you know which RadioButtonList the event was fired from
    }
}
```